# Most appropriate method for remotely storing and accessing audio files from an Android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm at an early stage of development (and experience as a programmer).  I would really appreciate some advice and insight.  I am developing an application on the Android platform that should allow users to record short 5-10 second audio files and store them on a remote database.  It should also allow any user to later locate and playback the sound file from any phone running the application.  
I have looked a little into storing them as blobs in a SQLite db, but I read that the speed of the database begins suffering at just 250bytes per row.  The files won't be huge but they will exceed this amount sufficiently to dissuade me from going headlong down this path.  There will be some basic information attached to each file.  Unless someone has a better idea, I will probably use the SQLite db for this alone, and include some sort of a pointer to the audio data.  What would be the most appropriate way to store the audio information? 
Again I really appreciate any advice or insight into this issue. 
Thanks, 
Adam

Comment: If the database is remote, then this is more a web server type of question than an android one - so you are not for example limited to sqlite as your database implementation (not that you are on android either, but it's a more obvious fit on an embedded system to use tools that are a non-optional part of the installation than it is on a server scaled to support whatever solution you chose)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bad idea to store the audio data directly in the database.
A better approach would be to store it in files and save filename in the database.